# Count number of items in a row with domains

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy

I'm having trouble trying to get the total manpower in my attributes table.

This is the desired outcome:

| MAN_1 | MAN_2 | MAN_3 | TOTAL_MANPOWER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Technician | Null | Null | 1 |
| Engineer | Surveyor | Technician | 3 |

MAN_1 to 3 are attached to a domain to allow users to select from a drop-down list (Engineer, Surveyor, Technician).

I've tried using field calculator (Python) with this code: `TOTAL_MANPOWER = len(!MAN_1!, !MAN_2!, !MAN_3!)`, but the calculation includes everything in the drop-down list. i.e., 9 instead of 3 (assuming all 3 columns are filled out)
Also, the code breaks when "Null" is selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using cursors seems to work:

```
import arcpy

fc = r'C:\folder\data.gdb\featureclass'
fields = ['MAN_1','MAN_2','MAN_3','TOTAL_MANPOWER']

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[3] = len([val for val in row[:3] if val is not None])
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

BERA's answer can also be used directly in the field calculator :

```
len([val for val in [!MAN_1!,!MAN_2!,!MAN_3!] if val is not None])
```

Note that this works that your "null" are No Data value and not the text "null".

Alternatively, as you have a small list of workers and no risk of typographic errors because of the use of a drop down list, you can type the full list in your code, which could be useful if you need the count of, e.g., Engineers and technicians only.

```
len([val for val in [!MAN_1!,!MAN_2!,!MAN_3!] if val in ['Engineer','Surveyor','Technician']])
```